# Flutter: How to pause music playing with cron [workmanager]?

Tags: flutter, android-workmanager, workmanagers

How can I pause music playing using workmanager?
I got an exception error: **MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pause on channel assets_audio_player)** when trying to pause the music.

I want to implement a function **Bed time** which allow user to set their bed time, so I will pause the music on time set.

Dependencies:

1. workmanager: ^0.5.1
2. assets_audio_player: ^3.0.5

```
//GLOBLE
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((taskName, inputData) async {
    switch (taskName) {
      case rescheduledTaskKey:
        if (player.assetPlayer.isPlaying.value) {
          await assetPlayer.pause();
        }
      
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
//MAIN
Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);


//Example Task
Workmanager().registerOneOffTask(
   "1",
   rescheduledTaskKey, 
   initialDelay: const Duration(seconds: 5),
);
```